# How do you query a LDAP from a web application for SSO?

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on

Need to query an LDAP from a .NET app to create a single sign on scenario, is this feasible?

Comment: Is this something you are developing?  I would be extremely surprised if there wasn't already a built-in library for ldap.

Answer (score 1):

You can query LDAP from .NET without any issues.

What would you expect to receive could be an issue.
You probably will not be able to retrieve a password in any form your would be able to use for authentication to any other application.

You should look into one of the OpenID implementations or SAML would be my "off-the-cuff" recommendation.